# Vb.net Property Get and set values without Private variables

Tags: vb.net, properties, reference

Greetins,

I am programmer from some time only, I have certain doubts in fundamentals, could you please clarify on the following:
Case 1:

```
Public Class BillItems
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
        Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
        End Sub

        Private _BillIdValue As String


        Property BillId As String
            Get
                Return _BillIdValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                If Not _BillIdValue = value Then
                    _BillIdValue = value
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
End Class
```

Case 2:

```
Public Class BillItems
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
        Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
        End Sub


        Property BillId As String
            Get
                Return BillId
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                If Not BillId = value Then
                    BillId = value
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
End Case
```

Does case 1 and case 2 yield same result, I mean is a private value necessarily in there?, can we use property itself to use its own value in its Set and get statements?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you actually tried using case 2? - What result *did* it yield when you set the `BillId`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't imagine that Case 2 is going to run without causing a stack-overflow exception. You are essentially making an infinite loop that is going to constantly call itself.

Case 1 would be the right way to do it.

If you are using .Net 4 you could just do this (without the further Get/Set code):

```
Property BillId As String
```

This will generate the private member variable (`_BillId`) for you.

Edit:

You could try this to raise the event:

```
Property BillId As String
    Get
        Return _BillIdValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If Not _BillIdValue = value Then
            _BillIdValue = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("BillId")
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Yes, that is true, but how can I get the Notification even fire if I just use "Property BillId As String"

Comment: @surpavan - you can't do any validation in an auto implemented property - your only option is case 1 above. See [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 3):

In this article on MSDN about [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx) you can read that a property requires a standard syntax when you

```
Add code to the Get or Set procedure of a property, such as code to validate incoming values in the Set procedure. For example, you might want to verify that a string that represents a telephone number contains the required number of numerals before setting the property value.
```

Therefore, because you implement IPropertyChanged interface, you need to add code to the setter.
and write something like this.

```
Property BillId As String               
    Get       
       Return _BillIdValue               
   End Get               
   Set(ByVal value As String)                   
        If Not _BillIdValue = value Then                       
            _BillIdValue = value                   
            NotifyPropertyChanged("BillID")
        End If               
   End Set           
End Property
```

The second case is clearly wrong. (Infinite loop as someone else has already said)